# How to write criteria eqivalent of sql having count

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'd like to ask how to create hibernate criteria to get these employees who has more than one project. I have following entities

```
class Project{
    public String title;
    public Employee owner;    
}

class Employee{
    public String name;
    public Set<Project> projects;
}
```

I think I need to use query with subquery and the subquery should probably look like this:

```
DetachedCriteria sub = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Project.class)
  .createAlias("employee","e")
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.count("owner"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("e.name"))
  );
```

(it returns list of objects with owner name and number of his projects), but I don't know how to use it with main criteria query, to compare if projects number is greater than 1.

This hql returns the same results I want to get with criteria:

```
from Project project inner join project.owner owner group by owner.name having count(project.owner) > 1
```

Comment: @Marcinek answers in that question don't help me.

Comment: Can you please clarify why this answers don't answer your question?